# Alternative to ng-deep while applying styles to a mat control

Tags: css, angular, sass

For a sidenav with an embedded iframe, i was getting double scrollbars,
I fixed that using

```
::ng-deep.mat-drawer-inner-container {
     overflow: hidden !important;
 }
```

This is now causing other mat-drawer-inner-container overflows to be hidden too. How can i fix this?

Comment: What if you prefix your rule with `:host`? `:host ::ng-deep ...`

Comment: I tried this :host ::ng-deep hides the other mat-inner-containers too

Comment: Create a stackblitz reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the scrollbar from the side panel you just need to add the below css to your style.scss

```
.mat-drawer-inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
```

}

Please Note: If you use this CSS in the sidebar component then it will not work!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style.scss without ::ng-depp, so maybe you put this inside some module where you need it.

```
// Remove scrollbar from mat-sidenav inner container
.mat-drawer-inner-container {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```